# Why am I getting "Write Access Violation: this was 0x7FF895E32BB3" when trying to reference *this in a class constructor?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, constructor

I have a program which requires one class (B) to be made in a class's (A) constructor with a reference to the class (A) that made it passed into it's (B) constructor. Rubbish description I know but I don't know how better to word it.

I'm getting the error at runtime and it's pointing to B's constructor where the reference to A is assigned to a variable.

Here's the smallest code I could make that reproduced the error:

```cpp
class A;

class B {
public:
    B();
    B(A &a);
    ~B();
private:
    A *m_a;
};

class A {
public:
    A();
    A(int x);
    ~A();
private:
    B m_b;
};

B::B() {}

B::B(A &a) {
    *m_a = a; //           Exception thrown: write access violation.
} //                       this->m_a was 0x7FF895E32BB3.

B::~B() {}

A::A() {}

A::A(int x) {
    m_b = B(*this);
}

A::~A() {}

int main() {
    A temp = A(10);
}
```

I've tried adding and removing default constructors and I've tried to make a separate function solely for the `m_b = B(*this)` line because other posts similar to this seemed to suggest that `*this` wasn't working because the object `*this` was referring to hadn't fully been made yet.

Call stack:

```
[External Code]
main() Line 40
A::A(int x) Line 32
B::B(A & a) Line 24
```

I hope the names A and B aren't too short to make the code difficult to read. I don't know what I'd call them otherwise.

I don't really know how to describe what my aim is without going into tons of detail about my original program which I don't think would be appropriate.

Thanks in advance to anyone that helps and sorry for the strange code - I'm pretty new to C++

Comment: This is like doing `int* i; *i = 10;`. Do you see a problem in this code?

Comment: `m_a` is an uninitialized pointer, so assigning to `*m_a` gives your program undefined behavior. I suspect the code should be `m_a = &a;`.

Comment: Beware that even if you fix this issue, it's possible your `B` object can end up pointing to an object whose lifetime has ended. E.g.  `B *b; { A a; b = new B(a); }` After this, the `m_a` member in `b` ends up pointing to invalid memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
*m_a = a;
```

This takes the ***existing*** pointer, `m_a`, and the object `a` gets assigned to whatever `m_a` is ***already pointing to***.

Unfortunately, this `m_a` is a completely uninitialized pointer, it's random garbage, and this comprises undefined behavior.

It is unclear what exactly the intent of the shown code is. Perhaps the intent here is to ***set*** `m_a` to the address of `a`, or

```
m_a=&a;
```

It's important to understand when working with pointers in C++ that pointers and the objects they point to are ***different, independent entities***. Each one can be assigned to, and it is important to understand the fundamental differences.

This should address the immediate undefined behavior here, but this overall approach is somewhat error prone and will often result in undefined behavior elesewhere, but as far as the reason for the crash, this is it.

Comment: Thank you! That makes a lot of sense.  Changing the code to `m_a = &a;` fixed my problem.

Comment: When you say that the approach is error prone, in what way? How else could B have a way to access the object that made it?

Comment: It is error prone in the sense that nothing stops the object referenced by the pointer from going out of scope and getting destroyed, leaving a dangling pointer behind. Say hello to your old friend, "write access violation". Pointers are very useful, and it is important to learn how to use them and how to use them correctly. It is also important to learn when ***not*** to use them.

Comment: How would it go out of scope?

Comment: It can go out of scope in many ways. Objects go out of scope all the time in C++. Objects in automatic scope go out of scope when their scope ends, by definition. `delete` makes objects in dynamic scope go away.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to dereference a pointer that has not been initialized, causing undefined behaviour, a segmentation fault normally.

Lets go through the code.

1. You call class A constructor, `A(int x)`
2. You call class B constructor during the assignment, so you enter constructor B before assignment is finished in constructor A
3. You dereference `m_a` before it's been assigned, since the constructor of class A is waiting for constructor B to finish running so that it returns and the assignment in constructor A gets completed; so, when you reach constructor B, `m_a` is still not assigned.

To solve this, you can rather change line 24 to:

```
m_a = &a;
```

This way, you're not dereferencing `m_a`. It'd be even better if you use a member initializer list, so your constructors would look something like this:

```
B::B() : m_a(nullptr) {}
B::B(A &a) : m_a(&a) {}
```